# After the codehaus closure what the new location for : http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.27.xsd ?

Tags: java, xml, enunciate

We have some XML file that refer to 'http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.27.xsd',  which is now gone.

Current sub I am using  :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stoicflame/enunciate/master/top/src/main/resources/META-INF/enunciate-1.27.xsd

What would be the ideal long term location for this file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New schema location:
http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/schemas/enunciate-1.27.xsd

Source: Commit on June 10, 2015.
https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/commit/7fbd78fa928430079469170bc107f01d1feabfe0